# TypeScript: How can I derive a type that has some parts of two separate interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

so I have

```
export interface Interface1 {
  relevantProp1: RelevantProp1;
  relevantProp2?: RelevantProp2;
  irrelevantProp1?: SomeRandomType;
  irrelevantProp2?: SomeRandomType;
}

export interface Interface2 {
  relevantProp3: RelevantProp3;
  irrelevantProp3?: SomeRandomType;
  irrelevantProp4?: SomeRandomType;
}
```

two interfaces. and I want to type a object like this

```
const obj = {
  relevantProp1: //..,
  relevantProp2: //..
  relevantProp3: //..
}
```

so it has parts from both interfaces but only partially.

I thought of a way to do it is
`interface Interface3 extends Interface1, Interface2 {}` and the type is `Partial<Interface3>`

but I am not sure there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Pick<Type, 'attr1' | 'attr2' | ...>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and union (`&`) to achieve that:

```
type Interface3 = Pick<Interface1, 'relevantProp1' | 'relevantProp2'> & Pick<Interface2, 'relevantProp3'>
```

That will be equivalent, in your example, to:

```
interface Interface3 {
  relevantProp1: RelevantProp1;
  relevantProp2?: RelevantProp2;
  relevantProp3: RelevantProp3;
}
```

Or, alternatively, use [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to remove unwanted attributes.